# Unable to call Laravel routes in Jquery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am unable to call laravel route outside laravel folder .

My route

```
 Route::resource('tmrate','WebServiceController');
```

My controller function to get and post

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    Teamrating::create($request->all());
        return response()->json(['response'=>'true','message'=>'Rating Submitted','code'=>201],201);

}


public function show($id)
{
    $teamratings=Teamrating::find($id);
        return response()->json(['response'=>'true','message'=>'ratings found','data'=>$teamratings,'code'=>201],201);

}
```

When laravel routes/url are hit using postman it works fine

```
 http://localhost/saniservices/public/tmrate/10       for get

 http://localhost/saniservices/public/tmrate?requestid=2&clientid=1&propertyid=1&servicesheetId=1&serviceTypeId=1&serviceDate=2017-05-05&rating=5&reason=Best service&comment=Great services and workd&teamId=1      for post
```

Now I am using this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <body>

 <form  action="#" method="post" id="idForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
 </form> 


  </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">



    $("#idForm").submit(function(){


        $.ajax({
                 url: 'http://localhost/saniservices/public/tmrate',
                 type: 'GET',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data:{"id":1},
                 success: function (data) {
                     alert('success');

                 }

             });

      });



  </script>
  </html>
```

But here I am not getting any response from api , i am not sure why is it so , i have tried lot to do but i am not getting any response

This above file is placed outside of laravel installation.

Comment: Do your browser dev tools show the request being made? what is the response? is the request URL correct with the parameters?

Comment: Submit form by method type POST. Now controller expects it, but you still call by GET.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is, in `ajax` the `type` specified is:

```
type: 'GET',
```

and in route.php the route is:

```
Route::resource('tmrate','WebServiceController');
```

here the type is `resource`. Change it to `get` and try again.

Comment: thanks, i was just blinded since it was so simple and obvious.